# Which model to follow for predicting count of visitors, if the independent variables are all categorical (date, and x(1-5 value))?

Tags: time-series, categorical-data, count-data, negative-binomial-distribution, poisson-regression

I have a dataset about the people visiting the website on each day of each month. Data consists of The session id of each visit , the number  of clicks made , country from where the person is , the kind of product clicked on each click and price of that product, the page number on the website on which the product was .

I have to predict the count of unique sessionid on a day of a month for each page of the website, what model should If I want to predict the users on each page on a future date? Also, I read about Poisson and negative binomial regression, in that case, should I drop all the other variables except day,month and page and then make a model